# Methods of transferring data securely between an iPhone app and an Arduino server

Tags: ios, arduino, security

I'm trying to make a secure protocol between an iPhone app and an Arduino server. The goal is that the iPhone app makes a request to an Arduino server and the server only processes it if it has the proper credentials of one form or another. I'm not really sure how to approach this problem. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Ethernet shield + SSL?

Comment: Don't think the Arduino has enough processing power/memory to run SSL on it. I'm already using an ethernet shield though

Comment: USB serial + PC + SSL?

Comment: I need it to be standalone

Comment: USB serial + ducktape + netbook + SSL?

Comment: @H2CO3 A diskette + pair of shoes + SSL?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are no truly secure communication options available on Arduino. The basic problem is that SSL libraries have not been ported to this platform, partly owing to the fact that the 8-bit processors the platform is built around are not very powerful. Having said that there are some things you can do, but you'll have to do them yourself:

[Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is a very insecure method of controlling access to HTTP pages so it isn't recommended.  [Digest access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication), on the other hand, employs one-way cryptographic encoding (hashing). It only requires MD5 library, which, is [actually available](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,37905.0.html) for Arduino. What you'll need to do is modify the source code for the [Web Server](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer) class to support digest access authentication: AFAIK it does not support it out of the box.

If this seems to difficult, you could implement something fairly basic (and not very secure, but better than nothing) yourself. It might look like this:

- The first GET request comes in from a client
- The server responds with "not authorized" response, embedding in the response a token which is related to (perhaps a hash of) the requesting IP address. You could make the original timeframe part of the hash as well, and give such tokens a limited lifetime.
- If the next request from the same IP address includes a hash based on some secret code + the token sent, the next request is honored.

Now this will not protect you from IP address spoofing, and many other things I probably haven't thought of. However, it will give you a modicum of security (and a tiny bit of security through obscurity, if you believe in this sort of a thing). You could ask for (slightly) more elaborate schemes on [superuser](http://superuser.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to just use authenticated messages built on shared secrets. The message will contain [at minimum] a message type, message body, timestamp, and message digest. You create the digest by HMACing the other stuff with a shared secret. (Type HMAC Arduino into Google for libaries and code.) The message is sent over TCP or UDP (i prefer it). The Arduino computes digest of message, checks it, validates data, and then acts on message.

One thing I like to do is implement port-knocking or something at the network layer in front of the application server. This prevents unwanted traffic from reaching the custom (and possibly vulnerable) command server. This can be done stealthily (see Silent Knock) or obviously. The network protections can also be implemented by a dedicated device that does the heavily lifting and disqualifies much rogue traffic before it reaches the Arduino.